# How can I select the ::before of a sibling element with css?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have created a checkbox using the following HTML:

```
<div class="chkbox">
  <input id="accept-filter" type="checkbox" class="filter-handler" checked=""> 
  <label for="accept-filter">
   ::before
   <span class="label-txt">I accept the terms</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

I would like to style the `::before` pseudo-element, but only when the checkbox is checked.

I have done this successfully using the `:has` selector:

```
.chkbox:has(.filter-handler:checked) label::before
```

However this doesn't work in Firefox ([it seems the `:has` selector isn't supported](https://caniuse.com/css-has)).

I was hoping there was a way to do this by using the `+` sibling selector, but the following doesn't seem to work ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/urbycoz/cdvjms8k/1/)):

```
.filter-handler:checked + label::before
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The approach you're trying to use is definitely viable, I've used it successfully dozens of times. Can you edit your question to include a working (or rather broken, presumably) example using a code snippet?

Comment: You can't write `::before` in the HTML. You have to set styles for it in CSS. (Currently the browser is not styling the before element because there isn't one.) However, if you just want a red border around the label, just remove the ::before bit in the CSS.

Comment: You haven't given the pseudoelement any `content` in that example, which will prevent it from showing. If you update the rules applied to it, your selector works just fine

Comment: the rule is correct, just add the missing `content: '';` to the pseudo element, [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/2r0zL61s/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you used will work. You can use the '+' selector to do this.

It works with a class name as well as a tag name as follows:

`.filter-handler:checked + .filter-label::before`

or

`.filter-handler:checked + label::before`

Find the below code

```css
.filter-handler:checked + .filter-label::before {
  content: 'Selected';
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  color: '#fff';
}
```

```html
<div class="chkbox">
  <input id="accept-filter" type="checkbox" class="filter-handler" checked=""> 
  <label for="accept-filter" class="filter-label">
   <span class="label-txt">I accept the terms</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: You're dead right, thanks. Turns out the issue was a missing semi-colon elsewhere in the css which was causing Firefox to fail to read that line correctly.